# When I upload the first installation Next JS project to the VPS server, it gives a 403 Forbidden error

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, http-status-code-403, vps

I did not make any changes to the Nextjs project and installed it on the VPS server as it was in the first installation. However, when I activate it with Phusion Passanger, I get a 403 Forbiden error on the site. And this has nothing to do with .htaccess permissions. I think there is a problem with webpack. Additionally, when I deploy the nextjs project on the server via SSH and run it in developer mode, I get a permision error.

@-ERROR-@

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Has anyone encountered this problem before or can tell me why?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.